# Java - Random.nextInt compilation error;_;

Tags: java, random, methods, undefined

So I'm trying to learn Java but errors like this are not helping :/
I was following the tutorial and then I got compilation error. I tried in many ways but nothing helps :(
Here is example code of what does NOT compile on my Eclipse:

```
public class coin {
public static void main(String[] args){

    Random rand = new Random();

    int result = rand.nextInt(2);

    if (result == 0){
        System.out.println("heads");
    }

    else if(result == 1){
        System.out.println("tails");
    }

    else if(result == 3){
        System.out.println("side. fix your random number generator");
    }

}

}
```

It gives me error:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random
at coin.main(coin.java:8)"

I give up - I'm out of ideas. Please help ;_;

EDIT: Yes, I tried Ctrl + Shift + O

EDIT 2: Now I get what was my problem. I was trying to import random with () at the end... "import java.util.Random();" That's why it didn't work - it's fine now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import this class:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Check if you are importing the correct Random class.